# Can what I seek not exist, two different queries showing on the same report/header query?

Tags: sql, sybase

I'm astonished that I can't find this, unless it does not exist.
I've been using SQL to write queries in my PMS for about five years-
I wanted to do something new.

Is there no way to put two (or more) queries into the same output statement, 
all to the same output?

Imagine I'm a bank, I have an SQL table with customer information, 
and the bank account # is primary key---

I have a second table with ALL transaction data, primary key is sequential, one of the other columns includes of course, the account number.

Is there really no way to have output that is a combination a select statement that produces the equal of a checking statement.

It shows ONCE at the top the records I choose from the customer information table. It then proceeds with the line items.  A simple header query.
then the long data query.  Then goes to the page break?

i.e.
Select customer.account, customer.firstname, customer.lastname, customer.everything else from customer table

then--

select transaction.number, transaction.date, transaction.type, transaction.debitamt, transaction.creditamt, transaction.whatever
where transaction.account equals customer.account and dates are between x&y
order by transaction.number

pagebreak on customer.account

I want to show the output of two different queries on the same report
then I want a new page for the next customer

really?  there is no provision for two different tables to be produced one after the other in this fashion?  they have to match as to content?  (union all)
as I don't need the customers name on every line of a transaction.

I've been searching for hours and can't find that this functionality exists....

Comment: you should remove everything unnecessary from your question and try to include the exact code / schema, and use formatting for it. Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: SQL is **NOT** (repeat **NOT!**) a "report generator". SQL provides great ways to get the information you need FOR a report, but it isn't equipped with controls like "page break".  While I'm here; What does "*my PMS*" mean?

Comment: Thank you,  that helps.
PMS is industry specific, shoulda explained..  Property Management System.


Given that I know it has an ODBC connector (I've used it from inside excel)

Can you suggest what software tool I can use locally to generate such a report-that would connect via ODBC, but not for a webserver, but locally run--  commercial or FOSS is fine...

Answer (score 0):

SQL can be used to provide the data needed for your report, e.g. the query might look something like this:

```
select
        c.account
      , c.firstname
      , c.lastname
      , c.all_other
      , t.number
      , t.date
      , t.type
      , t.debitamt
      , t.creditamt
      , t.whatever 
from customer_table c
inner join transaction_table t on c.account = t.account
where c.account = 'abcd'
and t.date >= '2018-04-01' and t.date < '2018-05-01'
order by
        c.account
      , t.date
;
```

But SQL is **not designed as a report writer**. It will supply the results of that query with information REPEATED for each customer in the columns coming from the customer table. This is NOT an accident or an error, it is by design and expected behaviour.

To "format" your report you need another tool e.g. you might use PHP and HTML to "format" the data into a "report". This extra tool is often referred to as a "presentation layer" and while the presentation layer may source the needed data using SQL it is up to that layer to meet your presentation needs.